# Session for every user unique or do I have to set it myself? If so how?

Tags: php

So I got an ini.php file which I included on top of every file. It includes my database connection + `session_start()`.

When the login of the user is succesful then I set a session which equals `$_SESSION['login'] = true`.

Now I can do stuff like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    include 'php/includes/login_form.php';
}

else {
    include 'php/includes/welcome.php';
}
```

What if I wanted this specific login to be specific to the user? Do I have to link the session somehow with the username on login?

Comment: Besides session hijacking, one session is always tied to just one user.

Comment: *Do I have to link the session somehow with the username on login* If you don't store which user is using that session, is there any point in having user accounts?

Comment: @Epodax It is not! The browser just gets a session id, all the other session data is stored on the server.

Comment: @Popnoodles how do I store the user in my session? Like this $_SESSION['login'] = $username?

Comment: @Asperger https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=php+session+tutorial+-w3schools

Comment: another perfectly valid question bombarded by downvote fairies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A session is always unique to one visitor. `session_start` generates a random session id, which it puts in a cookie, which only your current visitor will receive. On the next request, that cookie with the unique session id is picked up on by `session_start` and the session is resumed.

However, this by itself won't tell you which of *your* user accounts specifically the session belongs to. You'll have to record that information yourself. E.g.:

```
if (/* login successful */) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $loggedInUserId;
}
```

Comment: any security concerns?

Comment: Other than the usual security concerns with sessions like session hijacking? Nope.

Comment: I guess I will just intergrate an IP check, would you recommend that?

Comment: Yes and no. Especially for mobile users, IPs may suddenly change, causing a logout. Search around for Q&As concerning session security, you're not the first to ask and this has been discussed plenty.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. There are plenty of security answers here on stackoverflow, I will search around